# Custom colours not showing with android.Theme.Material

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

In my values-v21 folder I have the following style.xml, where I customise Theme.Material:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#880E4F</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#E91E63</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FCE4EC</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

However, I cannot see any of those colours when I run my app on Android API 23. I do call the theme in my android manifest: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`. I have tried the same with my standard values folder (=>API 21 or smaller, and I have the same problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In folder values-v23 add

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#880E4F</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#E91E63</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#FCE4EC</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

I hope that works!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It partly worked. But my Action Bar takes the same colour as my background (line 3). How can I set the action bar to colorPrimary(line 2)?
  
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/background</item>